# How do you clean mussel shells for serving appetizers at a wedding?

Tags: food-safety

We collected a bunch of mussel shells at Venice beach we wanted to clean them and use them to serve appetizers at our wedding celebration.

Answer (score 11):

Mussel shells are robust. Hot water, soap and a brush will work fine. If you have a lot the dish-washer is an option as well.

Comment: Dishwasher detergent can be pretty aggressive, I wouldn't count on the shells surviving that unharmed.

Comment: And don't use any vinegar or similar, they will dissolve

Comment: @MaxD I'm pretty certain they'd be fine with dishwasher detergent as they're calcium carbonate, and the detergent is alkaline (CaCO₃ reacts readily with acids, not with bases).  Eggshells are also calcium carbonate, and I've put them in the dishwasher to use for a craft project. The only worry might be that they'd fade a little.  However I'd use a program without a drying cycle and give them an extra rinse afterwards.  That's because being bowl-shaped and light, some of them will end up with water inside

Comment: @moscafj That's a different answer, received more upvotes than the answer you comment on - but OP can not accept it as a solution.

Comment: I would suggest if you're going to put them through the dishwasher, try *one* first to see how it affects the appearance.

Comment: @pipe...there you go....

Comment: @ChrisH: Put them in the dishwasher open-side down so the water won't pool?  Or if your rack will hold them, then standing vertically like a bowl.  Or maybe they're so light that some would probably get flipped over.

Comment: @peter they're definitely so light they'll get blown over if you layer them flat.  You could stand them up in the cutlery basket but they wouldn't get as well washed as they would spread out, and would tend to nest together as they moved around.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you remove all of the mussle meat. This might require some scraping. After good cleaning, perhaps with detergent, I would put them in some type of sanitizing solution and make sure they dry fully.

Comment: Would this + a good wash be sufficiently safe for guests with seafood allergies?  Probably a good idea to prep some alternate serving mechanism for some appetizers for guests with severe allergies that don't want to risk it.

Comment: I would not risk serving to guests with seafood allergies.  I don't know if could possibly trigger a reaction, but it would just be weird.  I would hope it is one of a selection of appetizers.  It would, of course, be obvious enough for people with allergies to self-police.

Comment: Agreed.  I mostly wanted to leave a reminder for the OP that they should consider this possibility and make sure there's a good snack option for people who don't want to eat out of seafood shells but are hungry when these are being served.